# For a discrete moving point, find its first coordinates where it lies in a circle

Tags: analysis, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm looking for a method to find the smallest $x$ as a function of $a_1$, $b_1$, $c_1$, $a_2$, $b_2$, $c_2$ and $r$ that satisfies the equation.

$$\left(\lfloor a_{1}+x\cdot\left(b_{1}-a_{1}\right)\rfloor-c_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(\lfloor a_{2}+x\cdot\left(b_{2}-a_{2}\right)\rfloor - c_{2}\right)^{2}<r^{2}$$

$a_1$, $b_1$, $c_1$, $a_2$, $b_2$, $c_2$ and $r$ are integer.

I am able to solve the equation using iterative methods, having first reduced the search interval. But I wanted to know if it was possible to solve it analytically.

This equation comes from a problem where a point moves on a discrete grid and the objective is to find the first point where it lies in a circle.

[image: Graphic representation of the problem]

If it's possible to solve this analytically, would it be possible to give me some advice ?
Or perhaps there is another, simpler way of finding this point ?

Comment: Find the smallest real $x$ where the line intersects the circle and then check if $\lceil x\rceil$ works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but which line are you talking about? Because the segment $\overline{ab}$ doesn't necessarily intersect the circle, in my example if the circle is positioned at $(8, -2)$ the point $(6, 0)$ is in the circle whereas the line doesn't intersect the circle.

Comment: Apologies, I misread where the floor function was. Perhaps you can bound the possible lattice points between two lines and compute if/where those lines intersect the circle.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing at the moment, but you still have to iterate over all the possible points between these two lines, and that's precisely what I'd like to avoid.